# Outlook cert error with online mailbox

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

All our mailboxes are now in Exchange Online / Office 365, and I have amended the autodiscover record to point to autodiscover.outlook.com. However, when running Outlook it still throws a certificate error, complaining about the self-signed cert on the Exchange server.

My question is: why is it connecting to this Exchange server at all? The mailbox is online. The autodiscover is pointing it online. There's literally nothing of interest on that Exchange server.

It's Outlook 2016 and Exchange 2016 CU13.

Comment: Is this after a migration from Exchange On-Premise to Exchange Online?
Are the PC's in a domain and using the Windows DNS?

Comment: Do you perharps access the internet via proxy with SSL interception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making an estimated guess you still get this warning after a migration from on-premise Exchange to Exchange Online.

You probably still have an active Service Connection Point (SCP) entry which is found by the Outlook Autodiscover functionality.

You can remove the SCP entry with the following PowerShell command in the Exchange Management Shell. (Replace *EXCH-SERVER-NAME* with the actual server name!):

```
Set-ClientAccessServer –Identity EXCH-SERVER-NAME -AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri $null
```

Comment: Interesting. So would the GPO setting 'Disable AutoDiscover' also fix the issue (on existing Outlook profiles), with the following settings:`Exclude the last known goode URL Enabled 
Exclude the SCP object lookup Enabled 
Exclude the root domain query based on your primary SMTP address Disabled 
Exclude the query for the AutoDiscover domain Disabled 
Exclude the HTTP redirect method Enabled 
Exclude the SRV record query in DNS Enabled `

Comment: Well anyway - this worked so thankyou!

Comment: Maybe cache configuration.